# How to write regexp for my string?

Tags: regex

I have the following sctring:

```
//- item:type /path/to/file/file.js flag
```

How to write regexp to get item, full path to file.js and flag(is optional) ?

**EDIT**: In javaScript

Comment: Do you have example values for `item`, `type` and `flag`?

Answer (score 1):

```
^//- ([^:]*):[^ ]* (.*\.[^ ]*) ?(.*)
```

in JavaScript:

```
"//- item:type /path/to/file/file.js flag".replace(/^\/\/- ([^:]*):[^ ]* (.*\.[^ ]*) ?(.*)/, "$1||$2||$3").split("||")
```

or

```
var pattern = /^\/\/- ([^:]*):[^ ]* (.*\.[^ ]*) ?(.*)/
var str = "//- item:type /path/to/file/file.js flag"
var match = pattern.exec(str);
if (match) {
    var item = match[1];
    var path = match[2];
    var flag = match[3];
}
```

Note the index within the `match` object is the group number (with 0 being the entire match, 1 and higher being each of the parenthesized matches in appearance order)

Comment: What's about multiple spaces?

Comment: "What's about multiple spaces?" Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Erik replace the spaces in the pattern with `\s+` (or ` +` [that is "space plus"])

Comment: @Erik you may wish to read up on basic RegExp syntax - try http://www.regextester.com/jssyntax.html